# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE productID = '1'' at line 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\edit_product.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\edit_product.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\edit_product.php on line 31

```
<?php
// Get the product data
$category_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$product_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

// Validate inputs
if ($category_id == null || $category_id == false ||
    $product_id == null || $product_id == false ||
    $code == null || $name == null || $price == null || $price == false) {
$error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
include('error.php');
} else {
require_once('database.php');

// Add the product to the database  
$query = 'UPDATE products
            SET categoryID = :category_id,
                productCode = :code,
                productName = :name,
                listPrice = :price,
            WHERE productID = :product_id';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id);
$statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
$statement->bindValue(':code', $code);
$statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
$statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();

// Display the Product List page
include('index.php');
}
?>
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to remove the leftover comma after this listPrice = :price, Shouldnt be a comma after the last field set

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after last field set.

```
$query = 'UPDATE products
            SET categoryID = :category_id,
                productCode = :code,
                productName = :name,
                listPrice = :price           -- no comma here
            WHERE productID = :product_id';
```